# Datepicker showing error only on focus out

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker

I am using material datepicker: `https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview`.

And I have async validator for it which calls API to do some validation. Async validator works but the error message is shown only when clicking outside the date field. So it appears on focus out. But I want it to appear after selecting date, so user dont need to click outside to see the error.

Is it possible to change it? Or its like that by design and cannot be changed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it was what you're looking for but there is `updateOn` property in the formBuilder options:

[image]

The usage should be something like:

```
MyFormGroup:FormGroup = this.FormBuilder.group({
  MyFormControl:[null,MyValidator]
},{asyncValidators:MyGroupLevelValidators, updateOn:'change'});
```

I didn't see it in the control level though but it might have it someway else.